# Для чего нужны мьютексы в C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

В C++ существет такое понятие, как мьютексы. Кто может объяснить мне, зачем они нужны?

Comment: для синхронизации потоков. Чтобы только один поток мог взаимодействовать с объектом

Comment: Понятие "мутексы" существует не в С++, а в одной из моделей синхронизации для параллельного программирования. Никакого отношения к С++ все это не имеет.

Comment: @AnT Сейчас народ повадился добавлять в С++ что не попадя. Например в std:: добавили библиотеку потоков. Может и мьютексы уже добавили, даже скорее всего да.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ну вот, представьте ситуацию - вы с женой одновременно кладете на свой семейный счет деньги. Примерно так:

```
int sum = howManyMoney();
sum += 10000;
MoneyToAccount(sum);
```

И то же одновременно делает жена - и вот как это у вас получается:

```
int sum = howManyMoney();
                             int sum = howManyMoney();
sum += 20000;
                             sum += 10000;
MoneyToAccount(sum);
                             MoneyToAccount(sum);
```

И что получится? Получится, что в банке стало всего на 10000 больше, а не на 30000. Плохо? Понятно, что для банка хорошо :), но для вас...

А вот если каждый код начинается с захвата мьютекса, и заканчивается его освобождением, то в силу гарантии атомарности захвата и невозможности одновременно владеть мьютексом нескольким потокам, какой-то поток захватит его первым, и положит свои деньги - второй же будет вынужден ждать. Только потом второй займется своими делами - которые опять же никто не сможет перебить.

Т.е. такой код может выполнять только один поток одновременно.

Потому юн и мьютекс - mutex, mutual exclusion, взаимоисключение...

Так примерно - понятно?

Comment: Да спасибо огромное)

Comment: Вторая часть примера плоха, не жизненно. Там должно быть вычитание.

Comment: @Harry [Получится, что в банке стало всего на 10000 больше, а не на 30000.] Как раз в Вашем примере в банке стало на 30000 больше, что и есть правильно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Почему же? Смотрите: считано левое значение sum, потом правое (пусть для определенности - нули), потом идет суммирование слева, в переменной 20000, потом правое - 10000, потом левая запись 20000, потом правая запись 10000, которая затрет левую...

Comment: @Harry После sum += 10000; sum равен 30000. Потом произойдут две записи подряд значения sum в базу данных банка. В результате будет записано 30000 как и нужно. Если же Вы считаете, что эти два процесса происходят на двух разных банкоматах, то тут Вам никакой мьютекс не поможет. Вернее поможет, но мьютекс должен быть на стороне сервера то есть в базе данных банка.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Да почему же после sum+=10000 станет 30000? Это же разные `sum` - в двух разных потоках. Знаете, почитайте лучше примеры в книгах - там, пожалуй, рассказывают подоходчевее, чем я - может, там вы поймете...